# ASP.net MVC Forms authentication and Authorize Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with Form authentication and wanted to restrict the users access to other URLs before authentication.

For from authentication, I'm using cookies. And the Login/Logout works fine.
Currently the flow is:

```
Login (GET) --> Login(POST)--> Home Page --> Logout
```

The moment I apply the `[Authorize]` attribute on any particular Action method of `HomeController`, the flow stops working.

Here's my Account Controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    ......
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Model model,string Id)
{
   ..........
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
  .....
}
```

If I put **[Authorize]** above action method "Index" of Home Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("/Home/Index")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
.......
}
```

The Login method redirects to itself:

```
Login (GET) --> Login(POST) --> Login(GET)
```

Here's my web.config setting for Forms authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

**EDIT**
My Login(POST) method looks like below:-

```
        if (IsAuthorized(username, password))
        {
            string groups = getUSergroups();//method to get groups where the user belongs to
            bool isCookiePersistent = false;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                                             model.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), isCookiePersistent, groups);

            //Encrypt the ticket.
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

            //Create a cookie, and then add the encrypted ticket to the cookie as data.
            HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

            if (true == isCookiePersistent)
                authCookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;

            //Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection.
            Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);



            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Can anyone please suggest any inputs to achieve this?

Comment: In what way does it stop working?

Comment: Is this a green-field development? If so, I implore you to consider ASP.NET Identity over forms auth. Forms auth is more-or-less dead.

Comment: Please provide the code of the Login POST action

Comment: @Luke If I add [Authorize] attribute, it stops working. If I try to Login using valid credentials, it doesn't go to the Home Page instead it redirects back to the Login page.

Comment: Post where/how you call `SetAuthCookie`.

Comment: @univ I've added the code, please see my "Edit" post

Comment: Have you verified that the cookie is actually being set in dev tools? This could also be related to a machine key. This could also be related to a machine key issue where the machine key is changing between posts and the cookie is no longer valid. Perhaps try adding a static machine key to your web.config